# How to use StopNamePattern from docker maven plugin

Tags: docker, maven

For testing purposes, I have to stop one of the docker containers and other containers should be up and running.
Would like to know how to use stopNamePattern from docker maven plugin to achieve it.

docker-maven-plugin used to start the docker containers.

With the below configuration, it stops all the containers though. I want to stop the container test-stub alone.
What am I doing wrong here? How to use stopNamePattern correctly?

docker-maven-plugin version 0.36.0
maven 4.0.0

```
<execution>
    <id>stop-test-stub</id>
    <phase>pre-integration-test</phase>
    <goals>
        <goal>stop</goal>
    </goals>
    <configuration>
        <stopNamePattern>test-stub</stopNamePattern>
    </configuration>
</execution>
```

Image config:

```
<image>
    <name>test-stub</name>
    <alias>test-stub</alias>
    <run>
        <hostname>test-stub</hostname>
        <memory>${docker.memory}</memory>

        <namingStrategy>alias</namingStrategy>
        <log>
            <file>${project.build.directory}/logs/test-stub.log</file>
        </log>
        <wait>
            <healthy>true</healthy>
            <time>300000</time>
        </wait>
        <network>
            <mode>custom</mode>
            <name>${docker.custom.network}</name>
            <alias>test-stub</alias>
        </network>
    </run>
</image>
```